# syncing local DB in xamarin with azure table storage

Tags: azure, xamarin

i am looking for the approach to use so that if the entities stored in my local DB are the same as my table storage ,there won't be a request to retrieve data and then it loads the data from my local DB
 and when some thing changes in my azure storage table lets say i want to make a version name for my azure storage table so that when version changes my app retrieve the new changes and when the version stay the same it loads the data from my local DB

and there is no code because i don't know the approach :(

but here is my retrieval method

```
 public ObservableCollection<CustomerEntity> CET1 { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<CustomerEntity>();
    public async void BTN_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string storageConnectionString = "mystringconnection";
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = DOTFORMS3.Common.CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString(storageConnectionString);

        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Mytablename");

        TableQuery<CustomerEntity> tableQuery = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>();

        foreach (CustomerEntity MyCustomerEntity in table.ExecuteQuery(tableQuery))
        {
            CET1.Add(MyCustomerEntity);              
        }

        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MyPage(CET1));
```

Comment: Have you checked the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/previous-versions/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-offline-data) ? It demonstrates `how to Enable offline sync with azure db`.

Comment: or in this case what is the word client refers to ?  `await client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store)`